# Understanding the structure of the return using line.getAt in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, data-structures

I am trying to get the first latitude of a line when the line is clicked by a user (for comparison to other values later)

The code section:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'click', function() {
    var pathClick = line.getPath();
    var Firstpath = pathClick.getAt(0);
    var FirstLat = Firstpath[0];
});
```

Firstpath will print out two values but FirstLat is undefined when I try to print. I am trying to understand the structure of Firstpath so that I know how the data is encapsulated and what methods work on it but I can't seem to find this documentation.

Comment: I edited your code. Please post complete code, correctly indented. When possible, provide a jsfiddle to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

[FirstPath](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) is a [MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) of [google.maps.LatLng objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).  To get the latitude, first get the first element, then call the lat() method on that:

```
getPath()       MVCArray.<LatLng>   Retrieves the first path.
getAt(i:number) *                   Returns the element at the specified index.

var FirstLat = Firstpath.getAt(0).lat()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Just learning javascript and google maps api and some of the documentation is vague.